# convergence of the sequence $10^{-n}$ in the p-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime. I am tasked to prove that the sequence $10^{-n}$ does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ for any $p$ where $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is the set of p-adic numbers.

For $p=2$ or $5$, we see that $|10^{-n}|_{p}$ goes to infinity so it can't be Cauchy. For $p\neq 2$ or $5$ i'm really confused here. We want to compute $|10^{-n}-10^{-m}|_{p}$. With the nonarchimedian norm we have $ |10^{-n-m}-1|_{p}\leq 1$. I don't really know where to proceed from here. Any hint would be very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=x/10$. Then if there is a limit $x_{\infty}$ to this sequence, $x_0=1, x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ then the limit must satisfy $f(x_{\infty})=x_{\infty}$.

Comment: Does your hint suggest for sufficiently large $n$, the limit would be $x_{\infty}=\tfrac{x_{\infty}}{10}$ which implies $x_{\infty}=0$. Which is a contradiction because norm doesn't go to zero?

Comment: Yep. That's where this goes. You need to show that $f$ is continuous on any $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: There is a more direct way. Given any $n$, the difference between $10^{-n}$ and $10^{-n-1}$ is $\frac{9}{10^{-n-1}}$, so the difference doesn't approach zero for any prime $p$.